Orbit equation solver giving wrong orbits
Recently I've become interested in simulating orbital mechanics using Kepler's equations, and in Unity I created my own equation solver by following this paper I found. However, inputting Earth's Keplerian elements found here, it gave me a polar orbit instead of what I was expecting. I'm aware that some of the elements were given in degrees, and I converted them to radians for my solver.
Here's the code for the solver, and yes, I've triple-checked that the huge rotation matrix in GetPositionInReferenceFrame is correct:
public class OrbitingScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject orbitingObject;

    [Header("Keplerian Elements")]
    public float semiMajorAxis = 10;
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public float eccentricity = 0;
    [Range(0, Mathf.PI * 2)]
    public float argOfPeriapsis = 0;
    [Range(0, Mathf.PI * 2)]
    public float ascendingNode = 0;
    [Range(0, Mathf.PI * 2)]
    public float inclination = 0;
    [Range(0, Mathf.PI * 2)]
    public float meanAnomaly0 = 0;

    [Header("Simulation Parameters")]
    public float centralBodyMass = 10;
    public float consideredEpoch = 0;
    public float gravityConst = 1;
    public float scale;

    [HideInInspector]
    public float standardGrav;

    float pi = Mathf.PI;
    float tau = Mathf.PI * 2;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        gameObject.transform.position =  GetPositionAndVelocityAtEpoch().Item1 / scale;
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public (Vector3, Vector3) GetPositionAndVelocityAtEpoch()
    {
        standardGrav = gravityConst * centralBodyMass;
        float meanAnomaly = CalculateMeanAnomaly();
        float eccAnomaly = CalculateEccentricAnomaly(meanAnomaly, 5);
        float trueAnomaly = CalculateTrueAnomaly(eccAnomaly);
        float distance = GetDistanceToCenter(eccAnomaly);
        Vector3 orbitalPosition = GetPositionInOrbitalFrame(trueAnomaly, distance);
        Vector3 referencePosition = GetPositionInReferenceFrame(orbitalPosition);
        return (referencePosition, Vector3.zero);
    }

    public float CalculateMeanAnomaly()
    {
        if (consideredEpoch == 0)
        {
            return meanAnomaly0;
        } else
        {
            float d_t = 86400 * consideredEpoch;
            float unclampedMeanAnomaly = meanAnomaly0 + d_t * Mathf.Sqrt(standardGrav / Mathf.Pow(semiMajorAxis, 3));
            return Mathf.Repeat(unclampedMeanAnomaly, tau);
        }
    }

    public float CalculateEccentricAnomaly(float meanAnomaly, int decimalPlaces)
    {
        float eccAnomaly;
        if (eccentricity < 0.8) eccAnomaly = meanAnomaly; else eccAnomaly = pi;
        float delta = Mathf.Pow(10, -decimalPlaces);
        float F = eccAnomaly - eccentricity * Mathf.Sin(meanAnomaly) - meanAnomaly;
        int maxIterations = 30;
        int i = 0;
        while (Mathf.Abs(F) > delta && i < maxIterations) 
        {
            eccAnomaly = eccAnomaly - F / (1 - eccentricity * Mathf.Cos(eccAnomaly));
            F = eccAnomaly - eccentricity * Mathf.Sin(eccAnomaly) - meanAnomaly;
            i = i + 1;
        }

        return Mathf.Round(eccAnomaly * Mathf.Pow(10, decimalPlaces)) / Mathf.Pow(10, decimalPlaces);
    }

    public float CalculateTrueAnomaly(float eccAnomaly)
    {
        float y = Mathf.Sqrt(1 + eccentricity) * Mathf.Sin(eccAnomaly / 2);
        float x = Mathf.Sqrt(1 - eccentricity) * Mathf.Cos(eccAnomaly / 2);

        return 2 * Mathf.Atan2(y, x);
    }

    public float GetDistanceToCenter(float eccAnomaly)
    {
        return semiMajorAxis * (1 - eccentricity * Mathf.Cos(eccAnomaly));
    }

    public Vector3 GetPositionInOrbitalFrame(float trueAnomaly, float distance)
    {
        float o_x = distance * Mathf.Cos(trueAnomaly);
        float o_y = distance * Mathf.Sin(trueAnomaly);
        float o_z = 0;
        return new Vector3(o_x, o_y, o_z);
    }

    public Vector3 GetPositionInReferenceFrame(Vector3 orbitalPosition)
    {

        float r_x = orbitalPosition.x * (Mathf.Cos(argOfPeriapsis) * Mathf.Cos(ascendingNode) - Mathf.Sin(argOfPeriapsis) * Mathf.Cos(inclination) * Mathf.Sin(ascendingNode)) - orbitalPosition.y * (Mathf.Sin(argOfPeriapsis) * Mathf.Cos(ascendingNode) + Mathf.Cos(argOfPeriapsis) * Mathf.Cos(inclination) * Mathf.Sin(ascendingNode));
        float r_y = orbitalPosition.x * (Mathf.Cos(argOfPeriapsis) * Mathf.Sin(ascendingNode) + Mathf.Sin(argOfPeriapsis) * Mathf.Cos(inclination) * Mathf.Cos(ascendingNode)) + orbitalPosition.y * (Mathf.Cos(argOfPeriapsis) * Mathf.Cos(inclination) * Mathf.Cos(ascendingNode) - Mathf.Sin(argOfPeriapsis) * Mathf.Sin(ascendingNode));
        float r_z = orbitalPosition.x * (Mathf.Sin(argOfPeriapsis) * Mathf.Sin(inclination)) + orbitalPosition.y * (Mathf.Cos(argOfPeriapsis) * Mathf.Sin(inclination));

        return new Vector3(r_x, r_y, r_z);
    }
}

Here's an image of the solver at t=60.

I'm not an astronomer and I'm very new to these equations and elements, so I know there's a good chance I'm misunderstanding something. Any ideas how to fix this?

I think you are using equations 9 and 10, which according to the footnotes are from Standish, E. Myles; Williams, James G.: "Orbital Ephemerides of the Sun, Moon and Planets" which looks like it's written in spherical coordinates. Therefore, the variable i for inclination may be 0 at the north pole and $\pi$ at the south and $\pi/2$ at the equator. I'll bet if you use 90° or $\pi/2$ for your "inclination" you'll get an equatorial orbit.

and if you add another 180° or $\pi$ to it you'll get the same orbit but going backwards. If that works, please feel free to post it as an answer. Welcome to Stack Exchange!

Thank you so much! I assumed i=0 would make a flat orbit because that's how everyone describes it, but I guess it's a quirk of the equations that I chose.

I'm looking forward to hearing if that works or not, please let us know!

MAJOR EDIT!
Upon further inspection, it appears the actual issue is that the axes of the rotation matrix are incorrect. Swapping r_z and r_y in the GetPositionInReferenceFrame function fixes the issue entirely. I believe this isn't an issue with the equation itself, rather that in the paper the z direction points up, while in Unity it points to the side. I'll leave the original solution up in case anyone has this issue.
As per user uhoh,

Therefore, the variable i for inclination may be 0 at the north pole
and π at the south and π/2 at the equator. I'll bet if you use 90° or π/2
for your "inclination" you'll get an equatorial orbit.

Adding this line of code at the beginning of the main function solved the problem:
float i = Mathf.Repeat(inclination + pi/2, tau);
Then you can use i for the rotation matrix instead of inclination.
